# Calculating field in Python pandas for multiple months based on different parameters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I am trying to create calculated_field for every every month from Year 1 to Year 10 based on parameter values in Data Frame 1. From the dataframe given below we need create Data Frame 2 from Data Frame 1. Basically each id will have 120 rows( 12 months * 10 Years) and this needs to be done for thousands of unique id. What would be the best way to do this using What is the best way to do this in pandas with optimal runtime:-

Data Frame 1:-

| ID | VAR1 | VAR2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ |
| 2 | MNP | QRS |
| 3 | UVW | STU |

Data Frame 2:-

| ID | YEAR_MONTH | VAR1 | VAR2 | calculated_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1_1 | ABC | XYZ | 5 |
| 1 | 1_2 | ABC | XYZ | 6 |
| 1 | 1_3 | ABC | XYZ | 7 |
| 2 | 1_1 | MNP | QRS | 11 |
| 2 | 1_2 | MNP | QRS | 12 |
| 2 | 1_3 | MNP | QRS | 13 |
| 3 | 1_1 | UVW | STU | 43 |
| 3 | 1_2 | UVW | STU | 44 |
| 3 | 1_3 | UVW | STU | 45 |

Comment: how are the `calculated_field` values determined?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is a Cartesian product.  You have not provided a formula for **calculated_field** so I've just provided an example.  More years,  change parameters to `range()`

```
# staright cartesian product to get combinations
# don't know formula for calculated field... just a demo calc
df2 = (pd.DataFrame({"YEAR_MONTH":[f"{y+1}_{m+1}" for y in range(10) for m in range(12)]})
 .assign(foo=1)
 .merge(df.assign(foo=1)).drop(columns="foo")
 .assign(calculated_field=lambda d: d.YEAR_MONTH.str.replace("_","+").apply(pd.eval)+d.ID)
)

# head & tail of DF
df2.iloc[np.r_[0:4,-4:0]]
```

|  | YEAR_MONTH | ID | VAR1 | VAR2 | calculated_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1_1 | 1 | ABC | XYZ | 3 |
| 1 | 1_1 | 2 | MNP | QRS | 4 |
| 2 | 1_1 | 3 | UVW | STU | 5 |
| 3 | 1_2 | 1 | ABC | XYZ | 4 |
| 356 | 10_11 | 3 | UVW | STU | 24 |
| 357 | 10_12 | 1 | ABC | XYZ | 23 |
| 358 | 10_12 | 2 | MNP | QRS | 24 |
| 359 | 10_12 | 3 | UVW | STU | 25 |